# Is a throw good in recursion?

Tags: c++, try-catch

So this toy problem is a graph problem using dfs to see if this entire course schedule is valid and doesn't have a course that can't be taken since its prereq can't be taken etc, etc...

I want to know if by using a throw in the visit method is good practice. Since if we found a cycle in the graph, I can just throw. Now does the throw totally ignore the stack and goes straight down until it finds a catch. If so, does that mean, instead of implementing visit method to return false when a cycle is found. It would be faster to just throw instead of returning false all the way down the stack? Is this good practice for production level code. or is the return bool method better?

```
class Solution {
public:
    bool canFinish(int numCourses, vector<pair<int, int>>& prerequisites) {
        vector<list<int>> vMap(numCourses);
        vector<bool> globalVisited(numCourses, false);
        for (auto it : prerequisites){
            vMap[it.first].push_back(it.second);
        }
        try {
            for (int i=0; i<numCourses; i++){
                if (globalVisited[i] != true){
                    vector<bool> localVisited(numCourses, false);
                    visit(vMap, globalVisited, localVisited, i);
                }
            }           
        }
        catch (...){
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }

    void visit(vector<list<int>>& vMap, vector<bool>& globalVisited, vector<bool>& localVisited, int i){
        if (globalVisited[i] == true){ //reached a deadend, try a different node
            return;
        }
        else if (localVisited[i] == true){ //found a cycle
            throw new exception;
        }
        localVisited[i] = true;
        for (auto it : vMap[i]){
            visit(vMap, globalVisited, localVisited, it);
        }
        globalVisited[i] = true;
    }
};
```

Comment: I would say no. Exceptions are not intended for use as control structures when a program is behaving in the expected manner. Finding cycles (or lack thereof) is the intention of the program. What you really want is a condition to stop recursing once a cycle is found. Additionally, is your program _really_ going to behave correctly, under all conditions, when the stack is unwound?

Comment: ok, but is throw technically still faster than a bool return down the stack? From my tests, it seems like it is.

Comment: Not usually. The returned boolean values take advantage of return value optimization, while the throw instead has to potentially destroy a bunch of objects. It's a toy program,so I'd suggest profiling the optimized code.